# exploit failed: nameerror undefined local variable or method `sysinfo' persistence service module error

Tags: metasploit

Recently I have been facing an error while using Metasploit.

I was trying to exploit Windows 7 with eternal-blue vulnerability.

After creating a meterpreter session I was trying to maintain a persistent connection. So, to do this I used  `exploit/windows/local/persistence_service`.

But whenever I try to exploit with this module I get the following error:

```
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.0.102:7878 
[-] Exploit failed: NameError undefined local variable or method `sysinfo' for #<Module:exploit/windows/local/persistence_service datastore=[#<Msf::ModuleDataStoreWithFallbacks:0x00007f61069f1b40 @options={"WORKSPACE"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069b9100 @name="WORKSPACE", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Specify the workspace for this module", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Module>, "VERBOSE"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069b8ef8 @name="VERBOSE", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Enable detailed status messages", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Module>, "WfsDelay"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106d80dd8 @name="WfsDelay", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Additional delay in seconds to wait for a session", @default=2, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "EnableContextEncoding"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106d7ece0 @name="EnableContextEncoding", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Use transient context when encoding payloads", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "ContextInformationFile"=>#<Msf::OptPath:0x00007f6106d7ead8 @name="ContextInformationFile", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The information file that contains context information", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "DisablePayloadHandler"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106d7e920 @name="DisablePayloadHandler", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Disable the handler code for the selected payload", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "SESSION"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106d79e98 @name="SESSION", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="The session to run this module on", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Post>, "RETRY_TIME"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106d770a8 @name="RETRY_TIME", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The retry time that shell connect failed. 5 seconds as default.", @default=5, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "REMOTE_EXE_PATH"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76ef0 @name="REMOTE_EXE_PATH", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The remote victim exe path to run. Use temp directory as default. ", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "REMOTE_EXE_NAME"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76d10 @name="REMOTE_EXE_NAME", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The remote victim name. Random string as default.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "SERVICE_NAME"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76b30 @name="SERVICE_NAME", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The name of service. Random string as default.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "SERVICE_DESCRIPTION"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76950 @name="SERVICE_DESCRIPTION", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The description of service. Random string as default.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "LHOST"=>#<Msf::OptAddressLocal:0x00007f612e593f30 @name="LHOST", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="The listen address (an interface may be specified)", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "LPORT"=>#<Msf::OptPort:0x00007f61069b87f0 @name="LPORT", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="The listen port", @default=4444, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "ReverseListenerBindPort"=>#<Msf::OptPort:0x00007f61069b8278 @name="ReverseListenerBindPort", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The port to bind to on the local system if different from LPORT", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "ReverseAllowProxy"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069b80c0 @name="ReverseAllowProxy", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Allow reverse tcp even with Proxies specified. Connect back will NOT go through proxy but directly to LHOST", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "ReverseListenerComm"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069bfa28 @name="ReverseListenerComm", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The specific communication channel to use for this listener", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse::Comm>, "ReverseListenerBindAddress"=>#<Msf::OptAddress:0x00007f61069bf5a0 @name="ReverseListenerBindAddress", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The specific IP address to bind to on the local system", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "ReverseListenerThreaded"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069bf3c0 @name="ReverseListenerThreaded", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Handle every connection in a new thread (experimental)", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "StagerRetryCount"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069bf0f0 @name="StagerRetryCount", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=["ReverseConnectRetries"], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The number of times the stager should retry if the first connect fails", @default=10, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "StagerRetryWait"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069bef38 @name="StagerRetryWait", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Number of seconds to wait for the stager between reconnect attempts", @default=5, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "PingbackRetries"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069be1f0 @name="PingbackRetries", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="How many additional successful pingbacks", @default=0, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PingbackSleep"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069be038 @name="PingbackSleep", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Time (in seconds) to sleep between pingbacks", @default=30, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDSeed"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069bd7a0 @name="PayloadUUIDSeed", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="A string to use when generating the payload UUID (deterministic)", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDRaw"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069bd5c0 @name="PayloadUUIDRaw", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="A hex string representing the raw 8-byte PUID value for the UUID", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDName"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069bd3e0 @name="PayloadUUIDName", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="A human-friendly name to reference this unique payload (requires tracking)", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDTracking"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069bd200 @name="PayloadUUIDTracking", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Whether or not to automatically register generated UUIDs", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "EnableStageEncoding"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069bc120 @name="EnableStageEncoding", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Encode the second stage payload", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "StageEncoder"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069c3f10 @name="StageEncoder", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Encoder to use if EnableStageEncoding is set", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "StageEncoderSaveRegisters"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069c3d08 @name="StageEncoderSaveRegisters", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Additional registers to preserve in the staged payload if EnableStageEncoding is set", @default="", @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "StageEncodingFallback"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069c3b28 @name="StageEncodingFallback", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Fallback to no encoding if the selected StageEncoder is not compatible", @default=true, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "PrependMigrate"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069c27a0 @name="PrependMigrate", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Spawns and runs shellcode in new process", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Windows>, "PrependMigrateProc"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069c2598 @name="PrependMigrateProc", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Process to spawn and run shellcode in", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Windows>, "EXITFUNC"=>#<Msf::OptEnum:0x00007f61069c1828 @name="EXITFUNC", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc_string="Exit technique", @enums=["''", "seh", "thread", "process", "none"], @default="process", @owner=Msf::Payload::Windows>, "PayloadBindPort"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069c1030 @name="PayloadBindPort", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Port to bind reverse tcp socket to on target system.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "AutoLoadStdapi"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069c0810 @name="AutoLoadStdapi", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Automatically load the Stdapi extension", @default=true, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "AutoVerifySessionTimeout"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069c05e0 @name="AutoVerifySessionTimeout", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Timeout period to wait for session validation to occur, in seconds", @default=30, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "InitialAutoRunScript"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069c03d8 @name="InitialAutoRunScript", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="An initial script to run on session creation (before AutoRunScript)", @default="", @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "AutoRunScript"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069c01a8 @name="AutoRunScript", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="A script to run automatically on session creation.", @default="", @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "AutoSystemInfo"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069c7f70 @name="AutoSystemInfo", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Automatically capture system information on initialization.", @default=true, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "EnableUnicodeEncoding"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069c7d18 @name="EnableUnicodeEncoding", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Automatically encode UTF-8 strings as hexadecimal", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "HandlerSSLCert"=>#<Msf::OptPath:0x00007f61069c7b10 @name="HandlerSSLCert", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Path to a SSL certificate in unified PEM format, ignored for HTTP transports", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "SessionRetryTotal"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069c7930 @name="SessionRetryTotal", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Number of seconds try reconnecting for on network failure", @default=3600, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "SessionRetryWait"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069c7750 @name="SessionRetryWait", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Number of seconds to wait between reconnect attempts", @default=10, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "SessionExpirationTimeout"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069c7570 @name="SessionExpirationTimeout", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The number of seconds before this session should be forcibly shut down", @default=604800, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "SessionCommunicationTimeout"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f61069c7390 @name="SessionCommunicationTimeout", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The number of seconds of no activity before this session should be killed", @default=300, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadProcessCommandLine"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f61069c71b0 @name="PayloadProcessCommandLine", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The displayed command line that will be used by the payload", @default="", @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "AutoUnhookProcess"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069c6fd0 @name="AutoUnhookProcess", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Automatically load the unhook extension and unhook the process", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "MeterpreterDebugBuild"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f61069c6dc8 @name="MeterpreterDebugBuild", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Use a debug version of Meterpreter", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "MeterpreterDebugLogging"=>#<Msf::OptMeterpreterDebugLogging:0x00007f61069c6bc0 @name="MeterpreterDebugLogging", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The Meterpreter debug logging configuration, see https://docs.metasploit.com/docs/using-metasploit/advanced/meterpreter/meterpreter-debugging-meterpreter-sessions.html", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>}, @aliases={"reverseconnectretries"=>"stagerretrycount"}, @defaults={"PAYLOAD"=>"windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp", "LHOST"=>"192.168.0.102"}, @user_defined={"SESSION"=>1, "LPORT"=>7878, "VERBOSE"=>false, "WfsDelay"=>2, "EnableContextEncoding"=>false, "DisablePayloadHandler"=>false, "RETRY_TIME"=>5, "LHOST"=>"192.168.0.102", "ReverseAllowProxy"=>false, "ReverseListenerThreaded"=>false, "StagerRetryCount"=>10, "StagerRetryWait"=>5, "PingbackRetries"=>0, "PingbackSleep"=>30, "PayloadUUIDTracking"=>false, "EnableStageEncoding"=>false, "StageEncoderSaveRegisters"=>"", "StageEncodingFallback"=>true, "PrependMigrate"=>false, "EXITFUNC"=>"process", "AutoLoadStdapi"=>true, "AutoVerifySessionTimeout"=>30, "InitialAutoRunScript"=>"", "AutoRunScript"=>"", "AutoSystemInfo"=>true, "EnableUnicodeEncoding"=>false, "SessionRetryTotal"=>3600, "SessionRetryWait"=>10, "SessionExpirationTimeout"=>604800, "SessionCommunicationTimeout"=>300, "PayloadProcessCommandLine"=>"", "AutoUnhookProcess"=>false, "MeterpreterDebugBuild"=>false, "TARGET"=>0}, @_module=#<Module:exploit/windows/local/persistence_service datastore=[#<Msf::ModuleDataStoreWithFallbacks:0x00007f6106d83880 @options={"WORKSPACE"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b46f68 @name="WORKSPACE", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Specify the workspace for this module", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Module>, "VERBOSE"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b46d60 @name="VERBOSE", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Enable detailed status messages", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Module>, "WfsDelay"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106d80dd8 @name="WfsDelay", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Additional delay in seconds to wait for a session", @default=2, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "EnableContextEncoding"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106d7ece0 @name="EnableContextEncoding", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Use transient context when encoding payloads", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "ContextInformationFile"=>#<Msf::OptPath:0x00007f6106d7ead8 @name="ContextInformationFile", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The information file that contains context information", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "DisablePayloadHandler"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106d7e920 @name="DisablePayloadHandler", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Disable the handler code for the selected payload", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Exploit>, "SESSION"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106d79e98 @name="SESSION", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="The session to run this module on", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Post>, "RETRY_TIME"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106d770a8 @name="RETRY_TIME", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The retry time that shell connect failed. 5 seconds as default.", @default=5, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "REMOTE_EXE_PATH"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76ef0 @name="REMOTE_EXE_PATH", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The remote victim exe path to run. Use temp directory as default. ", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "REMOTE_EXE_NAME"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76d10 @name="REMOTE_EXE_NAME", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The remote victim name. Random string as default.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "SERVICE_NAME"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76b30 @name="SERVICE_NAME", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The name of service. Random string as default.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "SERVICE_DESCRIPTION"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106d76950 @name="SERVICE_DESCRIPTION", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The description of service. Random string as default.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Modules::Exploit__Windows__Local__Persistence_service::MetasploitModule>, "LHOST"=>#<Msf::OptAddressLocal:0x00007f612e593f30 @name="LHOST", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="The listen address (an interface may be specified)", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "LPORT"=>#<Msf::OptPort:0x00007f6106b46608 @name="LPORT", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="The listen port", @default=4444, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "ReverseListenerBindPort"=>#<Msf::OptPort:0x00007f6106b46068 @name="ReverseListenerBindPort", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The port to bind to on the local system if different from LPORT", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "ReverseAllowProxy"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b45eb0 @name="ReverseAllowProxy", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Allow reverse tcp even with Proxies specified. Connect back will NOT go through proxy but directly to LHOST", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse>, "ReverseListenerComm"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b45820 @name="ReverseListenerComm", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The specific communication channel to use for this listener", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::Reverse::Comm>, "ReverseListenerBindAddress"=>#<Msf::OptAddress:0x00007f6106b45398 @name="ReverseListenerBindAddress", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The specific IP address to bind to on the local system", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "ReverseListenerThreaded"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b451b8 @name="ReverseListenerThreaded", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Handle every connection in a new thread (experimental)", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "StagerRetryCount"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106b44f10 @name="StagerRetryCount", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=["ReverseConnectRetries"], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="The number of times the stager should retry if the first connect fails", @default=10, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "StagerRetryWait"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106b44d58 @name="StagerRetryWait", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Number of seconds to wait for the stager between reconnect attempts", @default=5, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Handler::ReverseTcp>, "PingbackRetries"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106b4bf68 @name="PingbackRetries", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="How many additional successful pingbacks", @default=0, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PingbackSleep"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106b4bdb0 @name="PingbackSleep", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Time (in seconds) to sleep between pingbacks", @default=30, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDSeed"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b4b518 @name="PayloadUUIDSeed", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="A string to use when generating the payload UUID (deterministic)", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDRaw"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b4b338 @name="PayloadUUIDRaw", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="A hex string representing the raw 8-byte PUID value for the UUID", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDName"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b4b158 @name="PayloadUUIDName", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="A human-friendly name to reference this unique payload (requires tracking)", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "PayloadUUIDTracking"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b4af78 @name="PayloadUUIDTracking", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Whether or not to automatically register generated UUIDs", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "EnableStageEncoding"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b49e98 @name="EnableStageEncoding", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Encode the second stage payload", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "StageEncoder"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b49c90 @name="StageEncoder", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Encoder to use if EnableStageEncoding is set", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "StageEncoderSaveRegisters"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b49a88 @name="StageEncoderSaveRegisters", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Additional registers to preserve in the staged payload if EnableStageEncoding is set", @default="", @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "StageEncodingFallback"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b498a8 @name="StageEncodingFallback", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Fallback to no encoding if the selected StageEncoder is not compatible", @default=true, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Stager>, "PrependMigrate"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b48520 @name="PrependMigrate", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Spawns and runs shellcode in new process", @default=false, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Windows>, "PrependMigrateProc"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b48318 @name="PrependMigrateProc", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Process to spawn and run shellcode in", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=Msf::Payload::Windows>, "EXITFUNC"=>#<Msf::OptEnum:0x00007f6106b1f580 @name="EXITFUNC", @advanced=false, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc_string="Exit technique", @enums=["''", "seh", "thread", "process", "none"], @default="process", @owner=Msf::Payload::Windows>, "PayloadBindPort"=>#<Msf::OptString:0x00007f6106b1ed88 @name="PayloadBindPort", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Port to bind reverse tcp socket to on target system.", @default=nil, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "AutoLoadStdapi"=>#<Msf::OptBool:0x00007f6106b1e5e0 @name="AutoLoadStdapi", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=true, @desc="Automatically load the Stdapi extension", @default=true, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>, "AutoVerifySessionTimeout"=>#<Msf::OptInt:0x00007f6106b1e3d8 @name="AutoVerifySessionTimeout", @advanced=true, @evasion=false, @aliases=[], @max_length=nil, @conditions=[], @fallbacks=[], @required=false, @desc="Timeout period to wait for session validation to occur, in seconds", @default=30, @enums=[], @owner=#<Class:0x00007f612d933b00>>
Did you mean?  @sysinfo
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

So, can anyone solve this error ?

Comment: Sounds like an error with Metasploit. Try reinstalling.

Comment: I reinstalled the whole kali vm, updated the system and tried metasploit on a different OS (Debian Bookworm) but nothing resolved this error.

Comment: It sounds like a program error. I'd leave it with the devs: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/18647

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like an internal error.